# What are the various consensus mechanism and how are they best leveraged

Tags: consensus, finality

Just looking for a further rationale around each consensus mechanism and what they aim to solve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Babe, Aura, and Grandpa?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/204/what-is-the-difference-between-babe-aura-and-grandpa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a short nice write up on consensus here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/consensus
- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-consensus

If you're looking for more detailed info:

**PoW**

- https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/sc_consensus_pow

**Aura**

- https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/sc_consensus_aura

**BABE**/**GRANDPA**

- https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/sc_consensus_babe
- https://research.web3.foundation/en/latest/polkadot/block-production.html
- https://research.web3.foundation/en/latest/polkadot/block-production/Babe.html
- https://polkadot.network/blog/polkadot-consensus-part-1-introduction
- https://polkadot.network/blog/polkadot-consensus-part-2-grandpa
- https://polkadot.network/blog/polkadot-consensus-part-3-babe
- https://research.web3.foundation/en/latest/polkadot/finality.html
- https://github.com/w3f/consensus/blob/master/pdf/grandpa.pdf

This may be of interest to you:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/client/consensus

As @Squirrel noted, several of these are covered in [this post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/204/what-is-the-difference-between-babe-aura-and-grandpa).

Videos are nice too:

- [Block Production and Finalization in Polkadot by Bill Laboon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiEAnVECa8c)
- [Manual Seal & Instant Seal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhkV0jAcWDY)
- [Consensus in Substrate with Rob](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QE8svRKVYOU&t=727s)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To add a note regarding rationales:

We recently switched the consensues to manual/instant seal for [`substrate-contracts-node`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node).

The rationale was that this particular node is mostly used for local standalone development or in CI's ‒ so it's a big speedup if blocks are immediately produced.

Comment: Please remind me what is manual/instant sealing? I forget the details but is it something along the lines of: only when a transaction or an extrinsic is received, a block is produced?

Comment: @Purple_Turtle Yes exactly. Blocks are authored at every transaction, it makes transactions almost instant.

Comment: @Purple_Turtle This is the crate: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/client/consensus/manual-seal.

Comment: Awesome and thanks, see I'd have never known to look for this type of thing! Super useful for testing.