# Lightweight consensus implementation for Substrate in production?

Tags: consensus

What is the most relaxed and fastest consensus implementations for Substrate? I am considering to use something much faster and lightweight for processing of social messaging on Subsocial's L2 blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

There are trade-offs. I would recommend you start by reading:

- https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/consensus
- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-consensus

Especially this post:

- [What is the difference between Babe, Aura, and Grandpa?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/204/what-is-the-difference-between-babe-aura-and-grandpa)

Additional resources:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/client/consensus